# Html background not full when the browser window is minimized

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="logo_box">
                   <h1><a href="index.html" id="logo">logo<span></span></a></h1>
        </div>
    <header>

        <nav style="z-index:100;top: 42px;">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li id="menu_active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="About1.html"></a></li>
                <li><a href="Projects1.html"></a></li>
                <li><a href="About11.html"></a></li>
                <li><a href="About.html"></a></li>
                <li><a href="Projects.html"></a></li>
                <li class="bg_none"><a href="Contacts1.html">Contacts</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="wrapper">

            </div>
    </header>
```

In the above html code the background of the  logo box should spread for the full width 
It works properly on 1240px but it is not working when the widow size is reduced the background is not full so that the memu items are on the body background

Style css

```
#logo_box {background:#2c2d2e;padding:38px 0 22px 0px;border-radius:18px;-moz-border-radius:18px;-webkit-border-radius:18px;box-shadow:0 1px 3px #b7b7b7;-moz-box-shadow:0 1px 3px #b7b7b7;-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 3px #b7b7b7;behavior:url(js/PIE.htc);position:absolute;z-index:2;margin-top:-18px;width:100%;}
header {width:100%;padding-bottom:186px;position:relative}
```

the link of the webpage with the problem [a link](http://design3web.in/credor/)
jst minimize the browser window and you see the header problem

Comment: Can you please clarify a little? Do you want the `#logo_box` div to stretch to 100% of the page? And I'm sure you can put some more effort into your grammar. :)

Comment: Yes it should stretch 100% of the page irrespective of the width of the screen or window

Comment: "Irrespective?" Do you mean it should overflow no matter what?

Comment: i mean it should full screen size or window size a static thing which will not change with resolution changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this rule to your css:

`min-width: 1240px;`

The name is self explanatory even if the width goes under 1240px, the div will not get smaller then 1240 pixels.